# VBE6.dll not found when opening Access 2007 database in Access 2010

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-access, office-2010-beta

I have an access 2007 database that has some VBA code in it.  I need to open this database in Access 2010, but when I first open it I get an error that says:

> the expression on open you entered as
>   the event property setting produced
>   the following error: file not found:
>   VBE6.dll

I believe it's becuase Access 2010 references VBE7.dll when it loads up, and my database was built to reference VBE6.dll. I've tried putting VBE6.dll in the same folder that VBE7.dll resides in, hoping it would just get loaded up, but no luck.

What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like either a registration problem (i.e., which version of Access is registered as the canonical version) or a permissions problem. Try opening and close A2010 without any database. This should run the "reinstalling" process and properly register A2010. Then opening your database should work. Alternatively, maybe you're not running as administrator and you need to for some reason (though that's only relevant on Vista/Win7). Try changing your A2010 shortcut to run as administrator (or however you're launching A2010). Other than that, I have no idea -- this is something that should be fixed up for you on the fly without any issues.

Also, just Googling a bit, I notice that some advise disabling sandbox mode, and cite this Knowledge Base article:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239482/en-us